# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 513 target samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am getting the error stated in the title when trying to fit the model. The following script is supposed to classify between 3 types of traffic lights (red, green, yellow).

I have already printed the lengths of X_train and y_train, and they are the same lengths (they are both 513), so now I am confused how to fix this error.

```py
DATADIR = "/Users/path-to-data/"
CATEGORIES = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']

training_data = []

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
    print(class_num)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            new_array = np.expand_dims(new_array, axis=0)
            training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
        except Exception as e:
            pass

import random
random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(150,150, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3119fea43292> in <module>
      8 
      9 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 10 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    804         steps=steps_per_epoch,
    805         validation_split=validation_split,
--> 806         shuffle=shuffle)
    807 
    808     # Prepare validation data.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2652 
   2653       if not self._distribution_strategy:
-> 2654         training_utils.check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
   2655         if self._is_graph_network and not self.run_eagerly:
   2656           # Additional checks to avoid users mistakenly using improper loss fns.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_array_lengths(inputs, targets, weights)
    445                      'the same number of samples as target arrays. '
    446                      'Found ' + str(list(set_x)[0]) + ' input samples '
--> 447                      'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
    448   if len(set_w) > 1:
    449     raise ValueError('All sample_weight arrays should have '

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 513 target samples.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below points:

- Remove `new_array = np.expand_dims(new_array, axis=0)`.
- Add `X = np.array(X)` and `y = np.array(y)` before `train_test_split` function.
- You are not using `one-hot encoded` labels, so for above code to work change loss function from `categorical_crossentropy` to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.
- Change `model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))` to `model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))`, since number of classes are `3`, i.e. green, yellow and red.
- Also, consider normalizing the data before passing into the model.

New code:

```
IMG_SIZE = 150

DATADIR = "/Users/path-to-data/"
CATEGORIES = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']

training_data = []

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
    print(class_num)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
        except Exception as e:
            pass

import random
random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features) 
    y.append(label)

# X and y are currently of type list (list of python array), we will convert these to numpy array so we can feed it into our model.
X = np.array(X)   # (112, 150, 150, 3)
y = np.array(y)   # (112,)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```